# How to unvote on comments?

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-bydesign, comment

Occasionally I mistakenly upvote a comment.  There seems to be no way to undo this action.  Is this a bug?  A feature?  My missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to undo a comment upvote at this time, nor has there historically ever been a way to do so.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have any plans to change that?