# Is there a way to 'undo' a mistaken review?

Tags: discussion, support, review

A few minutes ago, I rejected a tag wiki edit (which didn't match the comment) as too minor (a one character change), and seconds after I did so realized that I had made a mistake, since it turns out that one character change will matter a lot.

I assume that [this](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/764/how-to-unvote-on-comments) answer applies also to other votes, including this one, but thought it was worth asking.

It'll be in the suggested edit review queue; I suppose sooner or later it'll get enough approves and go through, but it would be nice to now if there's a way to undo my error.

Edit: It looks like it ended up rejected; I have fixed it by repeating the change (but at least the comment now clearly explains why it was changed)

Comment: I have made such mistakes.  Most of the time I can rescue them by backtracking through the Web browser, recovering (hopefully) the original suggestion and implementing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Is it possible to undo a review action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152641/is-it-possible-to-undo-a-review-action)? So far, it is not.

As you said, there will be other reviewers which will end up approving the suggestion. If they do not, one can go over the tag wiki and edit it to fix the mistaken review.

Then, if you are still uncomfortable with the user who suggested the edit, it is possible to ping him/her on chat (or leave a comment) and explain.

But don't worry, because everybody makes mistakes once in awhile.

Comment: Thanks Andre ... my question looks like a duplicate of that. I tried a search, it looks like you did better with searching than I did.